# Multiple h1 tags on a single page

Tags: html, seo

Im working on a site that currently has multiple H1 tags per page.  What if any cost is there to pay in regards to SEO with this practice?

Is it worth me going through and switching these out/replacing with h2/h3's?

Comment: I'd be interested to hear from an SEO person what differences H1 tags make. HTML is a DOCUMENT structure, so the H1 tag is meant to represent a primary section of the document. I assume that labeling multiple (primary) sections of your webpage with h1's wont be that bad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nowadays Google indexing greatly prefers the content of your meta tags (most importantly meta "description") over the content of your h1 tags. Multiple h1 tags is not a problem, and in fact can it actually be a positive thing for SEO, as long as they are all semantically accurate.

Terms in the h1s are weighted more heavily, even if there are multiple h1s. For example, on a blog index, post title *should be* an h1, regardless of how many on your page, because you want to emphasize the importance of those titles to your page. Same would go for any page on any type of site that has major section divisions.

If your h1s are not semantic, then consider changing them, because it will make terms that are not relevant to your content be weighted too heavily.

And all of this is just for what the indexer decides your site is about. As far as page rank goes, that's almost all about quality of inbound links.

Comment: Currently, there's an H1 tag that heads every menu.  There's a top menu, left menu, and another H1 over the content header.  You think that's semantic?

Comment: Well it depends. Do the contents of the h1 menu titles accurately reflect what your site is about?

Comment: Why yes they do. Thanks for the answer. Love your music by the way.

Comment: @Chase, it's a different "Ben Lee" =).

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Ben but like in every other ranking factor the more H1's you have and the less power their keywords have SEO wise.